# Fundamental complex surface plotting including two real (from Euler relation) points

Tags: plotting

On the bounded $ (|z|< 1)$ surface,  (Thanks to Kuba),

> Plot3D[Evaluate[{ComplexExpand@Re[x^(I y)]}], {x, 0.4, 5}, {y, -10, 
>         10}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
>        Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize@8, Point@{E, Pi}}]

how do we place points $ (e,\pi, -1),(e,0, 1),.. ? $ on the real part of the Monge patch?

EDIT1

Section at $x=e$

```
Show[Plot3D[
  Evaluate[{ComplexExpand@Re[x^(I y)]}], {x, 0.4, 5}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Mesh -> {10, 20}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity@0.5}, PlotPoints -> 100],

 ParametricPlot3D[{ E, t, Cos[t]}, {t, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}],

 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02],
   Point[{{E, -3 Pi, -1}, {E, -2 Pi, 1}, {E, -Pi, -1}, {E, 0, 1}, {E, 
      Pi, -1}, {E, 2 Pi, 1}, {E, 3 Pi, -1}}], }]]
```

[image: Real_Intxn]

Comment: `Epilog` draws points over final 2D figure which contains already drown quasi-3D image. Therefore, you need another way:
`Show[<yours Plot3D without Epilog>, Graphics3D[{Red,PointSize[0.03],Point@{{your point1},{your point2},{your point3},{your point4}}}]]`

Comment: Thanks, got it, even full intersection line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[{ComplexExpand@Re[x^(I y)]}], {x, 0.4, 5}, {y, -10, 
   10},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Mesh -> 1,
  PlotStyle -> Opacity@0.2,
  PlotPoints -> 50],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{{E, Pi, -1}, {E, 0, 1}}]}]]
```

[image]